# ¿Desuscripción? ¿Desuscribir?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

En cualquier website en inglés frecuentemente podemos encontrar un botón o enlace "*unsuscribe*", para dar de baja una suscripción. ¿Cómo traducir esto en español en una sola palabra? Existen expresiones más largas como "Dar de baja la suscripción" o "Cancelar la suscripción". Pero busco algo más compacto como *desuscribir*.

*Desuscribir* en principio es una palabra bien formada pero no aparece en el diccionario de la RAE, ¿sería correcto o suena demasiado artificial?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aunque «desuscribir» sea morfológicamente correcto, es preferible usar las equivalencias en español [con más solera](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=darse+de+baja%2Cdesuscribirse%2Cdar+de+baja%2Cdesuscribir&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=), cuando estas existen y son perfectamente válidas.

Como bien dices, «dar de baja la suscripción» puede ser demasiado largo cuando hay que encajarlo en un botón o un espacio reducido dentro de un diseño maquetado. Personalmente, utilizaría «dar de baja», que tiene once caracteres, solo uno más que «unsubscribe», o «darse de baja», que tiene trece, dependiendo de lo que se vaya a dar de baja, una cosa externa o al propio usuario.

Comment: +1 Aunque "Desuscribir" no me parece tan mal, "Dar de baja" es probablemente preferible

Comment: la "se" es necesaria? "darse de baja" o podría ser "dar de baja" sin mas?

Comment: @DanRosenstark Depende. Puedes "dar de baja algo" o puedes "darte de baja (a ti mismo)".

Comment: @Chewie Gracias, pero: podés "dar de baja la lista"? Parece usual sólo para el caso del médico que te da de baja...

Comment: Dar de baja suena perfecto en España más no así en hispanomérica. Por aquí es más frecuente _desuscribir_, o mejor aún **Cancelar Suscripción** aunque sea más larguito.

Answer (score 4):

Aunque para otro uso quizá no te recomendaría lo mismo, si estás traduciendo -o haciendo- una página web o un programa de ordenador es importante no hacer nunca experimentos. Olvida eso de *"desuscribirse"*.

Una solución que no suele sonar mal es el lenguaje telegráfico: "Cancelar Suscripción" o, si el contexto lo deja claro, simplemente "Cancelar" o "Darse de baja".

El idioma Español es más *verboso* (?) que el inglés y vas a tener alguno de esos problemas siempre.

Comment: De Chile he recibido newsletters con "Desuscribirse" de una cadena de supermercados grande. La palabra me parece algo rara ya que no soy hispanohablante nativo. Tal vez por allá haga más sentido. Si quieres usar un español más universal, te recomendaría `Cancelar suscripción`.

Answer (score 3):

Otras posibles alternativas pueden ser:

- *Cancelar* suscripción.
- *Anular* suscripción.

Comment: Great point, another way to go at the same idea

Comment: Estas suenan mucho mejor en hispanomérica. _Darse de baja_ suena muy de España.

Answer (score 1):

Soy Email Marketing Specialist, y aunque "dar de baja" sea correcto, y "desuscribirse" no sea tan familiar, otros términos que pueden usarse son "desafiliarse", "autoexcluirse" y "desinscribirse". Tú eliges el sabor!